# how to hide status bar in Iphone application

Tags: ios4, statusbar

how to hide status bar .

in sdk 3.1 or lower version it is possible by adding this code in

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

[application statusBarHidden:TRUE];
```

}

but in 4.1 this method is not available in delegate class. i can see some site like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

it is also not working.
any body know that  how it will possible in iPhone sdk 4.1 ?

thanks and regards..

Comment: @Zebs answer is the best for me and has the most votes, people should consider it instead of the accepted answer...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

if you are doing it on the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` there is an easier way of doing it:

The easiest way to hide the status bar (and this will work on any version) is to go into you `Info.plist`; right click to add a row and select Status Bar Initially hidden.

This will ensure every time you app launches the status bar will be hidden.

I can post scree shots if you need them, just let me know and hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

Just put in delegate class.

```
        [application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

It is working for me..I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 20):

Your method is now deprecated for iOS 5. You should use one of the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 4):

**In iOS 7** , add the below two items another item to **info.plist** :

> View controller-based status bar appearance  = NO
>
> Status bar is initially hidden = YES

Answer (score 3):

Please Add in Your AppDelegate Class

**[application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];**

(or)

Please Add In your Info.plist file add key **View controller-based status bar appearance** with value NO.and also **add Status bar is initially hidden** YES

It is really working for me