# How to hide the red bar under the iOS's status when recording?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, avaudiorecorder

I used AVAudioRecorder to record the voice.I found that a red bar (just like the bar when you calling in background) will appear under the status bar sometimes when I alloc it and begin to record.How to hide it?

Comment: Try hiding the status bar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264072/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-iphone-application

Comment: It's a red bar under the status but not the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Every app, including the stock Voice Memos app, will have the bar when it uses the microphone.

Comment: But it will appear and then disappear immediately, the view of my App will be shocked,how to avoid this?

Comment: Because it takes a moment for the system to realize that recording stopped (which it automatically does when your app is suspended).