# Red status bar shown while switching camera using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am facing very weird issue while switching between camera. When user switch the camera from front to rear, user can see the **red status bar** for a second then disappears automatically with slide up animation. I searched a lot on google & stack-overflow but no luck. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878991/hide-red-recording-status-bar-in-ios-app-when-not-recording) , but its related to `audio recording`. Here is my code

```
-(void)toggleCameraIsFront:(BOOL)isFront
{
    AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition;
    if (isFront) {
        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
        self.videoDeviceType = VideoDeviceTypeFrontCamera;
    }
    else {
        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
        self.videoDeviceType = VideoDeviceTypeRearCamera;
    }

    for (AVCaptureDevice *d in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo])
    {
        if ([d position] == desiredPosition)
        {
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];
            [self.session beginConfiguration];
            [self.session removeInput:self.videoInput];
            if ([self.session canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
            {
                [self.session addInput:videoDeviceInput];
                [self setVideoInput:videoDeviceInput];
            }
            else
            {
                [self.session addInput:self.videoInput];
            }
            [self.session commitConfiguration];
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Also after camera is switched & try to record the video then below method from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` not getting called.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This red status bar appears due to audio recording, as you've mentioned a question which also describe that this is due to audio recording.
In order to avoid this you need to remove the audio input from `AVCaptureSession`

```
[self.captureSession removeInput:audioInput];
```

where *audioInput* is `AVCaptureDeviceInput` object.

Please check [@bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055717/red-audio-recording-status-bar-flashes-while-app-in-foreground) answer for more clarification.