# about red audio-recording status bar

Tags: ios, record

when I use AVCaptureSession to recode video, I press Home button to put app into background, I received 'UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification' notification and stop record video. but red audio-recording status bar still show about 1s ,then it disappear. how can I resolve this problem?
I hope it don't appear!

Comment: Probably your microphone is still listening although your video is stopped.

Could you check the answers on post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878991/hide-red-recording-status-bar-in-ios-app-when-not-recording

Will this help you?

Comment: yes, you are right. my microphone is listening all the time,so it evokes this question