# Full screen modal view controller not covering status bar area

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having a `UISplitViewController` as root in my story board. The detail view controller is showing an pop over with a view controller embedded in a navigation controller.

I have a button in the pop over view controller that is showing the `UIImagePickerController` with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` as source:

`[self.controller presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];`

The status bar disappears but there is still a black bar in the status bar area and the `UIImagePickerController` starts below the status bar. But it is still in full screen height so it is getting cut in the toolbar Here is an image:

[image]

If I rotate the screen it jumps to full screen, but then when I dismiss the `UIImagePickerController` the `UISplitViewController` is suddenly behind and partly covered by the status bar. But when I rotate it again, the `UISplitViewController` jumps back to being below the status bar and everything is fine again.

If I instead of the view controller in the pop over present the `UIImagePickerViewController` from the root view controller like this:

`[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];`

Then it gets full screen like it should, but the pop over appears in front of the `UIImagePickerViewController`.

**(1) Why isn't the full screen presentation of the `UIImagePickerViewController` working like it should?**

**(2) Why is the pop over above the `UIImagePickerViewController` when I show it from the root view controller?**

**(3) What is the proper way to solve this?**

Comment: Check out this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264072/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-iphone-application

Comment: I know how to hide the status bar, and as I said in the question the status bar is actually hidden but the view controller doesn't occupy the space as it should. Please see the image.